# Ins widget from Ebay does not show when navigating using Gatsby LInk, but does with regular a tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have an ebay ad widget that does not show when initially navigating to the page it is on. I navigate to the page using links created with Gatsby's Link component. (`import {Link} from 'gatsby'`)

The jsx looks like.

```
<ins class="h-100 w-100 epn-placement" data-config-id="999999999999"></ins>
```

I have to ad this script to my head to get the widget to show.

```
<script async src="https://epnt.ebay.com/static/epn-smart-tools.js"></script>
```

(Removing async has no effect)

---

The component does load when I refresh the page or visit the page directly without navigating to it.

This problem does not happen if I use regular `a` instead of `Link`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `<Link>` (inherited from `@reach/router`) does not load the full page like a typical anchor (`<a>`) does, you may want to use a `<Link>`'s state to keep all  features and adding the loading for your eBay widget.

In your `<Link>` page would be:

```
<Link to={`/your-ebay-page` state={{ loadWidget: true }}> To Ebay Widget Page </Link>
```

In your eBay page:

```
const EbayPage = ({ location }) => {
  if (location.state.loadWidget) {
    return <ins class="h-100 w-100 epn-placement" data-config-id="999999999999"></ins>

  } else {
    // whatever
  }
}
```

*Due to the lack of code and project structure, this is just an approach or a workaround about how to solve your issue, you should adapt it to your specifications.*

Comment: I think the ins loads an iframe from ebay, but it doesn't do it with Link. I'm kind of confused by your example. `location.state.loadWidget` is just a boolean that I'm setting right? I want to return the ins 100% of the time. The problem is that the widget won't load with link. From what you're describing it looks like I would have to pass the ins component as an argument like `state={{widget: <ins class="h-100 w-100 epn-placement" data-config-id="999999999999"></ins>}}` and then do something like `if (location.state.widget){ return location.state.widget}else{create a widget}`

Comment: That doesn't seem like a very clean solution though, and I tried it out and ran into problems of things never loading. I think I'm just going to use `a` for now, unless I can find a simple clean solution, like `if (location.state.loadWidget){ reloadPage }` or something. Are there major downsides to that?